# SASS in Sublime Text - Compile main.scss when saving any @import files

Tags: sass, sublimetext3, libsass

I'm running Sublime Text, writing SASS and compiling with Libsass.

Each time I update an scss file which is imported via @import to my main scss file I need to then go back to the main.scss and recompile using the ctrl-b build shortcut.

Is it possible to automate the compile of this main.scss file when using ctrl-s save shortcut on any of the imported files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sass` in watch mode, and not have to press ctrl-B at all!

```
$ sass --watch main.scss:output.css
```